# Replace User Text Input In Chrome Extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I currently have this code that will replace specific cases user input with other characters and it works in browser. However, when I try to do this in a google chrome extension, the text does not get replaced. Is there a way to make it work for chrome extensions?

```js
$('body').on('input', 'input[name=address1]', function() {
  $(this).val($(this).val().replace('/', ' m. '));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" class="text" name="address1" id="address1" value=""/>
```

Comment: If it's the popup, note that it's a separate window so it has its own separate devtools: right-click inside the popup and select "inspect" in the menu. You'll probably see an error about jquery. To fix it, download jquery.js manually, put it in your extension's directory and load it just like you load your main script(s).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I downloaded the jquery js file and in my html file just called `<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>`.